# Excel catalog (order list) with multiple dropdownlist

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I would like to create an Excel catalog (order list) with three different and related dropdownlist.
In the first ddl I choose the category of the product.
In the second ddl I choose the subcategory depending from the first ddl.
In the third ddl I choose the final subcategory depending from the second ddl.

These three ddl must be repeated for several lines.

I've followed this example http://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/07/17/create-dependent-drop-down-lists-containing-unique-distinct-values-in-excel/ but it doesn't work for more than one row.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create list and Define Name for it in a column write the fruit list:

```
Apricot
Mango
Orange
Watermelon
```

and like your source table:

- select the list under Apricot and Define Name Apricot
- Select the list under Mango and Define Name Mango
- Repeat the same with Orange and Watermelon (don't leave blank spaces in the defined Name)

Select where you want the Drop Down List and choose:
 - Data Validation
 - Under settings choose List
 - select the Fruit List (Apricot till Watermelon)

In the second column select and choose:

- Data Validation
- Under settings choose List
- write: `=INDIRECT(A11,TRUE)`

change A11 with the corresponding Cell reference that contain the fruit
example: if B1 is the Mango replace A11 with B1

Indirect will read Mango for example and will return the list with the Name Mango

[image]

[image]